# Change date from yahoo_fin

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance, yahoo-finance, yahoo

Can I change the date from yahoo_fin?
For example: I want to know what was the MSFT's P/E Ratio 1 year ago.

If I want to know the P/E now, I can:

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as yf
pe_ratio = yf.get_quote_table("MSFT")['PE Ratio (TTM)']
pe_ratio
```

So how do I change the date?

Answer (score 0):

To get the financial info (contains revenue, profit, EPS, and more) for a given time:
https://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/#get_financials

To get the market cap at a given time:
https://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/#get_stats_valuation

Both dataframes should have columns as the dates. Then essentially just need to convert the market cap to the proper float number (I believe it's pulled as a string) and you can divide whichever earnings metric you're looking for by the market cap!